# send Data to SQL DataBase with nodeJs

Tags: sql, node.js, forms

I'm new with nodeJs, I'm trying to send data from my form to DataBase using nodeJs but I didn't understand what I have to do I found many codes on the internet but no one works.Can anyone explain to me what I have to do?

thank you.

Comment: check this [package](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to save data passed from html form into your mysql database:

first install these packages:

```
npm install --save mysql body-parser
```

[body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) *Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body property.*

Then we will create a simple form with one input field assuming we are collecting only the user email

Your form

```
<form method="POST" action='/register'>
 <input type="text" name="email" class="form" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
 <button>Join Now</button>
</form>
```

Then you will need to setup some route handler to handle the submission of the form here we will create a route handler for `/register` to save an email

Your app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "username",
  database: "database_name",
  password : 'your_password'
});

app.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    const email = req.body.email;

    const data = { 
        email
    };

    connection.query('INSERT INTO table_name SET ?', data, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.send('Email inserted successfully');
    });
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on port 8080...');
});
```

Comment: Thank you things are more clear to me , but the insert  is not working my data base is empty .

Comment: You need to provide your database credentials otherwise it should throw an error in the console